# Authentication error when trying to Insert fields in MongoDB with flask

Tags: python, sql, reactjs, mongodb, flask

I'm trying to use flask to create fields in MongoDB using the codes below

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds119406.mlab.com:19406/")

mydb = myclient["my_database"]
mycol = mydb["my_collection"]
# print(mydb.list_collection_names())
db = myclient.database
print(db)

mydict = {"team_name": "team1" }

x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
print(x.inserted_id)
```

The right credentials have been passed in the URI but I get the error below

OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1600853835, 1), '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1600853835, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xa7\xe7\xff\xc0\xde\xff\x8a\xda\xcd\xf8\xddx\x03\xeb\x01\xae\x03\xc5\xb3G', 'keyId': 6829134799643344898}}}

My application is currently being hosted on Google Colaboratory. Any insight on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. The credentials I used was restricted to certain databases so I had to specify the database of interest in the url.